# Writing data from txt file to database in node js

Tags: sql, node.js

I read data from a text file:

```
const byline = require('byline');
const fs = require('fs');

var stream = byline(fs.createReadStream('C:/Users/../test.txt'));
var index = 0;
var headers;
var data = [];

stream.on('data', function(line) {
    var currentData;
    var entry;
    var i;

    line = line.toString(); // Convert the buffer stream to a string line
    //line = Buffer.from(line, 'latin1').toString();
    if (index === 0) {
        headers = line.split(/[ ]+/);
    } else {
        currentData = line.split(/[ ]+/);
        entry = {};
        for (i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
            entry[headers[i]] = currentData[i];
        }
        data.push(entry);
    }
    index++;
});
stream.on("error", function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
stream.on("end", function() {
    console.log(data);
    console.log("Done");
});
```

That works just fine. So now i am trying to write this into a my database. Therefore i implemented this part at the end of the stream, when all of the data has been read.

```
stream.on("end", function() {
    console.log(data);
    console.log("Done");

    for(h = 0; h < data.length; h++){ 
        let name = data[h].Name;
        let id = data[h].ID;
        let text = data[h].Text;
        let text1 = data[h].Text1;
        let text2 = data[h].Text2;
        let text3 = data[h].Text3;


        Conn.query('INSERT INTO Config SET ? ', { Name: name, ID: id, Text: text, Text1: text1, Text2: text2, Text3: text3}, function (error, result, fields) {
            if (error) throw error;

        });
    }
    return res.send({ error: false, data: result, message: 'New configuration has been created.' });
});
```

But it seems like this does not work. What am i missing?

Comment: Please give some more info on the library you use or details about errors if you get any.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
stream.on("end", function() {
  console.log(data);
  console.log("Done");
  var promises = [];
  for (h = 0; h < data.length; h++) {

    let name = data[h].Name;
    let id = data[h].ID;
    let text = data[h].Text;
    let text1 = data[h].Text1;
    let text2 = data[h].Text2;
    let text3 = data[h].Text3;
    promises.push(new Promise(function insertIntoDatabase(resolve, reject) {
      Conn.query('INSERT INTO Config SET ? ', {
        Name: name,
        ID: id,
        Text: text,
        Text1: text1,
        Text2: text2,
        Text3: text3
      }, function(error, result, fields) {
        if (error) reject(error);
        else resolve();
      })
    }));
  }
  Promise.all(promises)
    .then(function(data) {
      res.send({
        error: false,
        data: result,
        message: 'New configuration has been created.'
      });
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log("Error occured due to : ", err);
      res.send({
        error: true,
        data: null,
        message: 'Error during config'
      });
    });

  //It is a bad practise to have a async operation that can throw error inside a synchronous loop
  /*
   for(h = 0; h < data.length; h++){ 
          let name = data[h].Name;
          let id = data[h].ID;
          let text = data[h].Text;
          let text1 = data[h].Text1;
          let text2 = data[h].Text2;
          let text3 = data[h].Text3;

          Conn.query('INSERT INTO Config SET ? ', { Name: name, ID: id, Text: text, Text1: text1, Text2: text2, Text3: text3}, function (error, result, fields) {
              if (error) throw error;

          });
      }

    */

});
```

Comment: That does not work either but i can't locate the problem

Comment: The file could not be found. That was the problem. I could solve it by copying the file into the root directory of my node js project, setting the path to `./test.txt` Why is that?